# Is there a way to open an interactive Command Prompt from a service?

Tags: windows, jenkins, cmd

When I try to execute "*vstest.console.exe*" file in Jenkins CI (service mode), it responses

> Error: Could not start test run for unit tests for Windows Store app:
>   Unit tests for Windows Store apps cannot be run from a service or non
>   interactive process. Please run unit tests from an interactive
>   process..

However it will be able to run successful if I execute the same command from a Command prompt.

So I want to ask if there is a way to open Command Prompt from a service such as Jenkins CI.

I have tried with "*start ExecuteVSTest.bat /I /K /REALTIME*" but the result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to open Command Prompt from a service. However I am able to resolve the problem between Jenkins CI and "vstest.console.exe".

We just need to deploy Jenkins from the WAR file via Tomcat server instead of installing Jenkins service native package.

Since the Tomcat is running in the console mode so Jenkins CI won't have the same trouble when executing "vstest.console.exe" as when it run in service mode.

Comment: It's exceptionally difficult to break out of Session 0 isolation (where services run) - by design.